# Missing compile/runtime error when inlining

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, contravariance

I have the following classes/traits in Scala

```
trait Write[-T] {
    def add(elem : T);
}

class ContraListWrapper[T] (var list : List[T]) extends Write[T]  {
  def add(elem : T) = { 
    list = elem :: list
  }
}

def bar(list : Write[Number]) = {}
```

Invoking the method with a List of Object or list of Numbers works, thanks to contravariance of the Write trait.

```
var list : List[Number] = Nil;
var wlist = new ContraListWrapper(list);
bar(wlist);

var list : List[Object] = Nil;
var wlist = new ContraListWrapper(list);
bar(wlist);
```

When I invoke bar with a list of Integer, I receive a compile error in Scala. This is expected; Integer not a supertype of Number (but subtype)

```
var list : List[Integer ] = new Integer(1) :: Nil;
var wlist = new ContraListWrapper(list);
bar(wlist); //error: type mismatch; 
//found   : contra.this.ContraListWrapper[Integer] 
//required: contra.this.Write[Number]
```

But when I inline a variable declaration of list of Integer, the compile error is gone and it even seems working. (I can added element to the list in the method **bar**)

```
var list : List[Integer] = new Integer(1) :: Nil;
bar(new ContraListWrapper(list)); //no compile- nor runtime error
```

---

Edit: answers thx to Rex Kerr in **bold**

1) How it this possible? **First type Integer is chosen, with inlining Number**

2) Why isn't this the case without the inlining? **Scala can take appropriate type**

3) Why I wont event get a runtime error? **Because Lists are covariant**

Ps. I know I can get contravariance without the trait and wrapper, and with a bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` is covariant, so `List[Number]` is a supertype of `List[Integer]`.  In the second case, Scala looks at the code and goes, "Huh, bar wants something typed with Number, so let's see if we can get `ContraListWrapper` to return that.  Sure we can--we can tell it it's getting a `List[Number]` instead of a `List[Integer]`."

In the first case, the type is already fixed.

You can demonstrate this to yourself by changing the second case to

```
bar(new ContraListWrapper[Integer](list));
```

This gives a compile time error as it should, because the compiler is not free to choose the type as `Number`.